# Lua : Not all URLs load via sockets and http(s).request, yet all work in a standard browser?

Tags: http, https, lua

I have a couple of calendar URLs I’m trying to call, and both work when i enter the URL into the browser, however when I try to call them via Lua and http(s).request, only one of them works ?  Please could someone help me understand why, and what needs to be done differently to make the other one work ?

```
local socket = require 'socket'
local http = require "socket.http"
local ssl = require 'ssl'
local https = require 'ssl.https'

local calendarUria = "https://ics.fixtur.es/v2/ipswich-town.ics"
local calendarUrib = "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/en-gb.uk%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics"

print("Fixtur.es Football (URL A) returns the following?")
local responseBodya, responseCodea, responseHeadersa = https.request(calendarUria)
print(responseBodya, responseCodea, responseHeadersa)

print("Google UK Holidays (URL B) returns the following?")
local responseBodyb, responseCodeb, responseHeadersb = https.request(calendarUrib)
print(responseBodyb, responseCodeb, responseHeadersb)
```

If you run the code above, only the second Google (URL B) returns anything..

UPDATE : i did wonder if there were ‘redirects’ occuring…

As looking up http.request, it has a feature for that, which I’ve never used before, has anyone reading this ?

```
http.request{
  url = string,
  [sink = LTN12 sink,]
  [method = string,]
  [headers = header-table,]
  [source = LTN12 source],
  [step = LTN12 pump step,]
  [proxy = string,]
  [redirect = boolean,]
  [create = function]
}
```

UPDATE 2 : Checking the URL via Wheregoes.com, it suggests there are no redirects occuring, so that is perhaps not it..

Date Traced: 2021-11-21 11:23:32 GMT

User Agent: Wheregoes.com Redirect Checker/1.0

#CodeRequested URL
200https://ics.|fixtur.|es/v2/ipswich-town.|ics
Redirects: 0
1200https://ics.fixtur.es/v2/ipswich-town.ics
Trace Complete - 3 - text/calendar; charset=utf-8

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I worked my way through a variety of different `http.requests` scripts and found the following one worked in this case.

```
local http = require("ssl.https")
local ltn12 = require "ltn12"
r = {} -- init empty table
local res, code, headers, status = http.request{
url="https://ics.fixtur.es/v2/ipswich-town.ics",
sink = ltn12.sink.table( r )
}
print("status=".. tostring(status))
print("response= ".. table.concat( r, "" ) )
```

If anyone has time, I’d love to understand what occurs differently with this answer vs my original http.request post..